# Sharing Data between threads in TestNG

Tags: testng

I have a `testmethod` in `testNG` with `threadPoolSize = 10` which creates records in a database

I need to calculate the total time taken by all the threads to create all the records 
Please help me in finding the same.

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 10, invocationCount = 10)
public void testCreate(){
       long StartTime = new Date().getTime() ; 
        //operation to create records
       long EndTime = new Date().getTime() ;

     }
```

How do I calculate time taken by all threads in the above code?

The above code gives me time taken by only one thread at a time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TestNG, but if it's possible I would setup a pre-test and post-test hook which compare the start and end time.

Answer (score 0):

I would call an external function something like startTick(), which would track the startTime  and then once set, will not be overwritten and an endTick() which would collect all endtimes.  In the afterTest, I can do endTick - startTick..something like :

```
startTick(){
  if(startTime == null)
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
}

testCreate() {
  startTick(); 
        //operation to create records
  endTick();
}

endTick(){
    endTime = new Date().getTime();
}
@AfterTest
afterTest(){
  endTime - startTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to publish the data about test time, so that it could be used in report, not used in the other threads of the same test.

For this you could store result of each tests in some central location and find total later. Would following work for you?

```
public class TimeTest {
    Map<Long, Long> timeRecord = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>();

    @Test(threadPoolSize = 10, invocationCount = 10)
    public void testCreate(){
        long threadID = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        long startTime = new Date().getTime() ; 

        //operation to create records

        long endTime = new Date().getTime();
        long diffTime = endTime - startTime;
        timeRecord.put(threadID, diffTime);
        // Log time taken
        System.out.println("TestMethod[" + threadID + "] TestTime: " + diffTime);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void displayTime() {
        long runtime = 0;
        for (Long threadID : timeRecord.keySet()) {
            runtime += timeRecord.get(threadID);
        }
        System.out.println("AfterSuite TotalTime: " + runtime);
    }

}
```

If you want to time the whole test, not just the portion of it, you might use `ITestResult` interface provided by TestNG.

```
@AfterMethod
public void recordTime(ITestResult testResult){
    long threadID = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    long timeDiff = testResult.getEndMillis() - testResult.getStartMillis();
    // Log time taken
    System.out.println("AfterMethod[" + threadID + "] TestTime: " + timeDiff);
}
```

However, the times might be different from the one above, since there might be additional overhead.

Comment: using a static volatile field for the total time worked for me.. Thanks